# "variable xxx might not have been initialized" when calling static method that returns variable of the same type and the same name of the type itself

Tags: java, jls

Why does it fail with the error shown below? I'm not sure where in the JLS to look for the restriction to do something like this.

```
public class A {

    static A foo() {
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A A = A.foo();
    }
}
```

Error at compile time

```
A.java:14: error: variable A might not have been initialized
        A A = A.foo();
              ^
1 error
```

Comment: The big clue here is that the error message talks about "variable A" and points to the "A" in "A.foo()". That means the compiler thought that A was a variable, not a type.

Comment: And, if you give your classes and variables short silly names like `A`, you deserve everything you get :-)

Answer (score 7):

The variable hides the class of the same name. That's part of why there are [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html).

---

As Patricia notes in the comments, this is actually known in the JLS as [obscuring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.2):

> In these situations, the rules of [§6.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5) specify that a variable will be chosen in preference to a type, and that a type will be chosen in preference to a package.

---

In your case, you get a compilation error because the variable hides the type, as the declaration is treated before the method call. It's the same as doing the following:

```
public class A {
    public void foo() {
        String s = s.substring(0, s.length());
    }
}
```

You get the same kind of error:

```
A.java:3: variable s might not have been initialized
        String s = s.substring(0, s.length());
                   ^
1 error
```

In the comments, you say you don't find where the JLS says your construction is illegal. It's not illegal in itself, the result due to the obscuring is. Consider the case with 2 classes, where you can also get unwanted calls due to the obscuring, which is not illegal, just confusing:

```
public class A {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("A.foo()");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A B = new A();
        B.foo();
    }

    public static class B {
        public static void foo() {
            System.out.println("B.foo()");
        }
    }
}
```

What do you think the output is?

```
$ javac A.java
$ java A
A.foo()
```

Comment: See the JLS on ["Obscuring"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.2)

Comment: But I can't find the specific part in the JLS that says it is illegal and that in a sentence like that the variable name is hiding the type name.
Furthermore if I'm not wrong `=` operator is evaluated from right to left so the compiler could be able to process the right side (where the variable doesn't still exist) and after that process the left side, this is, the variable declaration and assignment, the last only an empirical explanation

Comment: Well, no, the compiler does not read backwards. The declaration is read first, and may serve to infer types in the RHS expression, in the case of static methods, and will always serve to check types anyway. It's not just a by-product of the method call.

Comment: Also, it's not illegal per se, it's just that in that case you end up with an uncompilable expression. With 2 classes A and B, you might get a compilable program which does not what you think it does, for example.